# Problem with POST request from React.js component to Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send data from client's inputs based on React.js to server written in Node.js which put it to DB. I have no errors and after submit, new records show in database but they are empty. I have two inputs and I'm joining them in one string and trying send it to DB (so DB has one property). Can you check my code and see what is wrong? Maybe something with headers...

This is function in React component:

```
  addCompetitor = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = this.state.draftCompetitorName;
    const lastname = this.state.draftCompetitorLastname;
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/competitors`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name: `${name}${lastname}` })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
   };
```

This is server POST response:

```
  app.post("/competitors/", urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    const newCompetitor = new Competitor({ name: req.body.name });
    newCompetitor.save().then(competitor => res.json(competitor));
  });
```

And it's app configuration:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type",
    "X-Requested-With"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

Comment: New records do have the name set or its empty ?

Comment: New records do not have name set, they are empty.

Comment: Did you use `app.use(bodyParser.json());` and then check?

Comment: You should then first debug your backend code, add some debug info with console.log (dumping the captured body data) or put a breakpoint and inspect the request. Something like : `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` before the new Competitor..

Comment: I think the error is with bodyparser. Have you added the middleware in the express or configured it correctly. try logging the request data with `console.log(req.body)` on the route

Comment: I tried and nothing showed up.

Comment: whats the output of console.log(req.body) ?

Comment: Sorry, I looked wrong. Output of console.log(req.body) is [object Object]

Comment: and when I changed it to console.log(req.body.name) is undefined

Comment: okay try this console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)) . this will log the data and we can see what data is being received

Comment: It is only this: {}

Comment: Thank you for help, but Navoneel solved it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not first install [**bodyparser**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). This parses incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, which will be available under the `req.body` property.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit: 100000
}))
```

Alternatively what is the express version you are using ? Is it greater than 4.16? Then you can also use

```
app.use(express.json());
```

See notes [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Modify your code

```
let databody = {
        "name": `${name}${lastname}`,
        "otherprop": this.state.otherprop
}
```

From frontend use 
      `body: JSON.stringify(databody),`

In express end remove `urlencodedParser` , should be like below:

```
app.post("/competitors", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: I did everything. But still the same. console.log(req.body) shows: [object Object]

Comment: Sorry, it works! I just had to change back 'Content-Type' to 'application/json' because I changed it because of another answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomaszPaczka you have to sync both request headers with what your controller is expecting. Either 'json' or 'x-www-form-urlencoded' as 'Content-Type' will work fine if the headers and format of body are correct

Answer (score 1):

You are using urlencodedParser as a middleware so I guess you used `bodyParser.urlencoded({})` but your request is sending a json format. Try adjusting your request by adding the following header:

`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

**EDIT:**

Also body should be in the following format:

`` body: `name=${name}${lastname}` ``

Comment: Still the same. And with this header when I console.log(req.body) in server route, it showed errors: POST http://localhost:5000/competitors/ 500 (Internal Server Error) and Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: I don't understand, what is also=another?

Comment: that was just to indicate that you can pass more than one parameter in the same string. I edited the answer to match your request

Comment: It depends on which Content Type you are willing to use :)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to check all options which you guys telling me and I mixed it a little bit up so it didn't work. I know that your option could work too, it just that works better for me.